# Is CameraX api only for Kotlin or it is for java too?

Tags: android-camerax

When I went in a sample app code, it was mentioned to choose Kotlin while creating the project.

I have use camera2 API before.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here should be about a specific programming problem. Make sure your question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean developing a camerax based app. 
You can use java. They have sample app even in JAVA.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/camera/integration-tests/coretestapp